# C++ How to properly receive a file in Winsock?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, winsock, winsock2

I'm working on a CHAT Program in C++. And stuck upon a problem of sending/receiving file. My server side is Python that runs in background of Flask App accepting TCP Connections and forwarding incoming/outgoing data to chat clients. It has no problem and works great. My problem is on the client receiving. I added this feature of Sending and receiving file. While send goes out fine with no error (Tested and it works). Receiving on the client side has gave me a headache.

I'm using the following to receive the file whether it is binary or Text.

```cpp
// filebuf is defined as
// char filebuf[BUFFER];
// BUFFER is 1024.
void CHAT::recvFile()
{
 int fsize;
 std::ofstream recvfile(filename, std::ios::app, std::ios::binary);
 while ((fsize = recv(sockfd, filebuf, sizeof(filebuf), 0)) > 0)
 {
     recvfile.write(filebuf, sizeof(filebuf));
 }
 recvfile.close();
 respond("Received file.\n");
}
```

This works but the data is not written in the file fully. For Example; If I send a 144 kb File it will be saved on the other side as 142 kb. And the program just stops there.

Final Question; How do I receive a large/small file in C++?

EDIT : After @Algirdas Preidžius Response, I retested it. Here are some screenshots of the file before and after sent.

**This is before it's sent.**

https://www.upload.ee/image/10164543/ook.PNG

**This is after it's sent.**
https://www.upload.ee/image/10164544/wsa.PNG

Comment: Is this a typo: `std::ofstream recvfile(filename, std::ios::app, std::ios::binary);`? Shouldn't it be `std::ofstream recvfile(filename, std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);`?

Comment: Oh man! yes that was a Typo. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Have your server close the connection after sending the file. This should cause the `recv` function to exit on the client.

Comment: @WBuck Is there no other way? I can't just close the connection.

Comment: I'm more interested in testing to see if this fixes the issue (which I believe it will). One way to fix this is to use non blocking IO. This way when `recv` is called it will return immediately (whether it read data or not).

Comment: What I believe is happening is the `recv` function is blocking waiting for incoming data. The data that had already been read has not been fully flushed to the file you have on disk (which would explain the difference in size). Another way to test if you received the full file is to flush the `ofstream` after each write.

Comment: You need to indicate the end of data somehow, e.g. send the length before the data and count down, or close/shutdown the remote end.

Comment: @WBuck Okay it works. The file is transferred. But I need to find another way as in a Chat program killing a connection isn't the best choice.

Comment: @Lynx you were told exactly how to do that - send the file size before sending the file data. That way, you can read the size first, then read the data up to the specified count. No disconnect needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you can handle this situation.

- Message delimiters/line terminator
- Inserting the size of the message before the message
- Use non-blocking IO in conjunction with `select`

Here is a quick example of parsing the incoming message looking for a line terminator.
For example:

```
int fsize;
std::string filebuf( '0', 1024 );

while ( ( fsize = recv( sockfd, filebuf.data( ), filebuf.size( ), 0 ) ) > 0 )
{
     if( std::size_t index{ filebuf.find( "#end", 0 ) }; 
          index != std::string::npos )
     {
         // The line terminator was found so don't call the
         // the receive function again as there should be nothing
         // remaining in the stream to read.
     }
     /*Write the data to your file.*/
     filebuf.clear( );
}
respond("Received file.\n");
```

Note that this is a quick untested example showing you how you might parse an incoming message.

Comment: Bucky, I think I fixed it by adding a timeout. It works now. Thanks alot!